# Cannot register getText() in JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

I have a problem with `JTextFields` in java and cannot understand what the problem is. I am using a graphical interface with three `textFields` and when I try to use the `getText()` method for the `textfields` it only register the value of the last field of the three.

The code looks like following:

```
public void panelAddPipe(JComponent panel){
    this.textFieldMat = new JTextField();
    labelMat = new JLabel("Material:");
    this.textFieldLen = new JTextField();
    labelLen = new JLabel("Length:");
    this.textFieldDia = new JTextField();
    labelDia = new JLabel("Diameter:");

    ah = new AddHandler();

    JButton addPipe = new JButton("Add Pipe");

    textFieldMat.setSize(150, 20);
    textFieldMat.setLocation(40, 50);
    labelMat.setSize(150,20);
    labelMat.setLocation(40, 30);

    textFieldLen.setSize(150, 20);
    textFieldLen.setLocation(40, 100);
    labelLen.setSize(150,20);
    labelLen.setLocation(40, 80);

    textFieldDia.setSize(150, 20);
    textFieldDia.setLocation(40, 150);
    labelDia.setSize(150,20);
    labelDia.setLocation(40, 130);

    addPipe.setSize(100, 50);
    addPipe.setLocation(40, 250);
    addPipe.addActionListener(ah);

    panel.add(textFieldMat);
    panel.add(labelMat);
    panel.add(textFieldLen);
    panel.add(labelLen);
    panel.add(textFieldDia);
    panel.add(labelDia);
    panel.add(addPipe);

}

public void addItemPipe(){
    String tempMat = "";
    int tempLen = 0, tempDia = 0;
    boolean correct = false;

    System.out.println(textFieldMat.getText() + " " + textFieldLen.getText() + " " + textFieldDia.getText());

    try{
        tempMat = textFieldMat.getText();
        tempLen = Integer.parseInt(textFieldLen.getText());
        tempDia = Integer.parseInt(textFieldDia.getText());

        correct = true;
        System.out.println("correct: " + correct);

    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("correct: " + correct + " " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    if(correct){
        handler.addPipe(tempLen, tempDia, tempMat);
    }

    panelSouth.repaint();

}
public class AddHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        switch(ev.getActionCommand()){
        case "Add Pipe":
            addItemPipe();
            break;
        case "Add Panel":
            addItemPanel();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

the only `textfield` that is registered is the `textFieldDia.getText()` one
it throws an exception message: `For input string: "" at textFieldLen.getText()`

Comment: What is the output of your program? What do you mean by 'not registered'? What happens?

Comment: it goes into the catch with the message:
correct: false For input string: ""

Comment: so how can you say that only `textFieldDia.getText()` is working?

Comment: If i write text in all the textFields it only saves the text in the last one wich is textFieldDia.

Comment: what is the output of `System.out.println(textFieldMat.getText() + " " + textFieldLen.getText() + " " + textFieldDia.getText());`?

Comment: the output is two blank spaces followed by the text i entered in the textFieldDia textfield

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. For better help, consider including enough code to reproduce the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: From where have you called the `addItemPipe()`?

Comment: i called it in the `ActionListener` for the `addPipe` button, im sorry for my incompitance this is my first post ever in any forum and im not very good at programming or describing problems

Comment: So what you are basically saying that you want the user to write in the `JTextFields` and press the `JButton`. When you do so the text you have entered disappears excepting the `textFieldDia`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes exactly! Do you have any thoughts about what could be causing this?

Comment: I could tell you if you could add some more code to your post. first would be the complete code of the method `addItemPipe()`. Second would be the complete code of `ActionListner` that is attached to the `JButton`

Comment: Both should be in the code window, the `ActionListener` is in the bottom in a class called `AddHandler`

Comment: See what I suspect is that there is some kind of a code like `textFieldLen.setText("")` and `textFieldMat.setText("")` somewhere in your code and I feel they are the culprits.

Comment: 1. Show the complete exception message, not your interpretation of it. 2. You really should create a very small [minimal example program](http://sscce.org) and post it here with your question (not in a link). Otherwise we're going to have to continue this painful and frustrating game of trying to extract information from you in bits and pieces, and no one enjoys that.

Comment: @Blip i've searched my file for both `""` and `setText` but cannot find anything, this is a mystery...

Comment: Quick question and a guess (while we're waiting on your [minimal example program](http://sscce.org/)) -- Are you using inheritance anywhere in your program? More specifically do you have any classes that *extend* any other classes of yours -- now I'm not talking about extending from JFrame, JPanel or other Java core classes -- I'm asking if you have any classes of your own that extend other classes of your own. If you do, show and tell the specifics since your problem could be due to misuse of inheritance.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am just about to start creating the minimal example program now, i got to tired yesterday since i was sitting with the program for about 10 hours constant. But to answer your question, yes i do have inheritance, i have a baseclass called `Part` wich `Pipe` and another class `Panel` inherits. But since i am not using any of those in the exception handling i didnt think it would matter.

Comment: I found the problem while doing my minimal example program, it was a similar method as the `panelAddPipe` wich was called `panelAddPanel` which apparently didnt want to get on the same `tabbedPane`.
I will continue with my program and hopefully i will solve this new problem!

Thank you for all the support! 
@Blip
@HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I'm glad that you've solved your problem.

Comment: Thats good and best of luck